# date function to display 7-12-2012 instead of 07-12-2012 & 01-01-2012 as 1-1-2012

Tags: php

the date function is displaying 07-12-2012 instead of 7-12-2012

I am using this `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

I want to display 7th December 2012 as 7-12-2012

what about displaying month as 1-1-2012 rather than 01-01-2012  for 1st Jan 2012

Comment: You could make the question less ambiguous (and therefore answered more accurately/quickly) by explaining if the 7 is a day or month (and/or if the 12 is a day or month).  Eg "I want to display 7th December 2012 as 7-12-2012".

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
date("Y-m-j H:i:s")
```

`d` shows the days with leading zeros, `j` just shows the days.

Edit: On second glance, the string you are using is totally different to the output you want:

```
date("j-m-Y");
```

Should get you what you want.

Comment: For future reference as well (thought I'd add to this) there is a great reference on the php website: [Date Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: @Abhishek I want to help, I really do, but you should take 2 minutes to read through the link FluffyJack provided. It lists *all* the date formats and how to use them. By the way, the letter of the day is `n`!

Answer (score 1):

Use `j` instead of `d`.

```
echo date('j-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
date("j-m-Y");
```

Read about variables [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).